# List of capture devices using FFmpeg libav* libraries

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

Could anyone please tell me how can I obtain a list of devices using the FFmpeg libav* libraries like when I execute this ffmpeg command line:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

I am not referring to the Libav project.

Comment: Do you mean FFmpeg or Libav? They're two different projects. What operating system? What is the question about your command line? Is it not working, or…? Can you show us the output?

Comment: you can't AFAIK libav never got the dshow patches initially and never sync'ed with ffmpeg to get them...

Comment: @rogerdpack He's not asking about LibAV - he's just talking about the API of FFmpeg, which has libraries starting with libav*. He's asking how to get a list of devices in the API just like you can do in the CLI.

Comment: Yeah there isn't a way, at least not yet, to do it internally, see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow#Howtoprogrammaticallyenumeratedevices